# Cannot properly update attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I'm using polymer, and jquery to change an attribute of a tag, if one tag's attribute is false, using an if/else statement, currently the one I am using doesn't work, how would I make it work?

**HTML**

```
<p flex>Would you like notifications on?</p> <paper-toggle-button checked="false" id="onoff"></paper-toggle-button>
<p flex>Private Message Notifications?</p> <paper-toggle-button checked="true" id="pmn" class="blue"></paper-toggle-button>
<p flex>Game Update Notifications?</p> <paper-toggle-button checked="true" id="gun" class="lightgrey"></paper-toggle-button>
<p flex>Website Update Notifications?</p> <paper-toggle-button checked="true" id="wun" class="pink"></paper-toggle-button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var main = document.querySelector('#onoff');
var pmn = document.querySelector('#pmn');
var wun = document.querySelector('#wun');
var gun = document.querySelector('#gun');

if ( $('#onoff').attr('checked') == 'true' ) {
    // do this
} else {
    pmn.removeAttribute("checked");
    wun.removeAttribute("checked");
    gun.removeAttribute("checked");
    pmn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    wun.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    gun.setAttribute("disabled", "true");

}
```

I currently have `#onoff` `checked="false"` so the other toggles would automatically be disabled and the attribute `checked` would equal false, but it doesn't, anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Just use `if ($("#onoff").attr("checked"))` to avoid having code that is [stringly typed (#7)](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

Comment: Have you checked whether code inside `if` condition is being executed or `else`? You can first put `alert` inside both the conditions and check.

Comment: I added an `alert` and the alert isn't popping up, so the code isn't executing, why is that?

Comment: alert should pop up in either one, where does alert pops up i.e. in `if` or `else`?

Comment: I put the alert in `if` and `else`

Comment: if it is not popping up in `else` then that means your `if` condition is being satisfied, so it can be `type` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var main = document.querySelector('#onoff');
var pmn = document.querySelector('#pmn');
var wun = document.querySelector('#wun');
var gun = document.querySelector('#gun');

if ( $('#onoff').attr('checked') === 'true' ) {

   alert("Your book is overdue1.");
} else {
    //alert("Your book is overdue2.");
    pmn.removeAttribute("checked");
    wun.removeAttribute("checked");
    gun.removeAttribute("checked");
    pmn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    wun.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    gun.setAttribute("disabled", "true");

}
});
```

Comment: You have missed `$` for `('#onoff').attr('checked')` in your jsfiddle. Also, I hope you are using it inside a jQuery/JavaScript scripts at your end and here you have just put its code. Otherwise, it is working now.

Comment: I forgot to add `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this:

```
pmn.attr("checked", false);
wun.attr("checked", false);
gun.attr("checked", false);
pmn.attr("disabled", "true");
wun.attr("disabled", "true");
gun.attr("disabled", "true");
```

Or use this if you are using jQuery v1.6+

```
pmn.prop("checked", false);
wun.prop("checked", false);
gun.prop("checked", false);
pmn.prop("disabled", true);
wun.prop("disabled", true);
gun.prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Has the same outcome, the toggles are still active and `checked="true"`

Comment: Which jquery version you are using ?